# How to find a direction given the sunset

Tags: observational-astronomy

If one is situated at 50° latitude (meaning north hemisphere) and looks at sunset in the evening, by how many degrees you need to turn leftwards to find the meridian that goes through the point you are situated ? How about if you are situated at the north pole? I would like to look at this at some (any) time point of the year. I had troubles figuring out. I will appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/39670/16685

Comment: Thanks. I looked at that post. I do not think it helped me much to answer my question.

Comment: It's not that hard to look up tables of  sunset angle vs. day-of-year

Comment: It is not about finding a value rather then how you do that. But even after looking at tables I wasn't able to find an answer.

Comment: The second set of equations on this page will give the setting (or rising) azimuth.  You can use that to find any other azimuth.  Ships still use this method today to calibrate their compass.https://celestialprogramming.com/risesetalgorithm.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using SkyChoord to read in multiple coordinates.](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/16684/using-skychoord-to-read-in-multiple-coordinates)